# creating nested Json in Java

Tags: java, json, api, nested

Im trying to get the Json inside Json response of the rest api.

httpsConn.getInputStream() will be a Json like

> "data":[
>          {"id":"1","name:"aaa","score":"90"},{"id":"2","name":"bbb","score":"85"}
>          ]

Jave code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();             
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
response = (MarkResponse)objectMapper.readValue(httpsConn.getInputStream(), MarkResponse.class);
```

Pojo class:

```
public class MarkResponse {
    private int count;
    private List<MarkData> markData;
    //setter and getter.
}
public class MarkData {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

The response is like below, as I'm using the List inside my main pojo.

> {"headers":{},"body":"MarkResponse [count=2 markData=***[MarkData [id=1,
>   name=aaa], MarkData
>   [id=2,name=bbb]]***],"statusCode":"ACCEPTED","statusCodeValue":202}

What I'm expecting is,

> {"headers":{},"body":"MarkResponse [count=2
>   markData=***{"id":"1","name:"aaa"},{"id":"2","name":"bbb"}***],"statusCode":"ACCEPTED","statusCodeValue":202}

What is the code change i should make to get the expected output.

Comment: What type of object is wrapper of your response? I mean the class which consists headers, body,...

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand the sections "the response is like below" and "what I'm expecting is". What kind of markup is this? Is this the Java toString() representation of your response variable while debugging?

Comment: @Georg Muehlenberg : 1st one is what im getting after running the program and 2nd one is the expected output.

Comment: @Juraj - Im not getting ur question

Comment: @MSD Okay, and what kind of markup is this?

Comment: But what is response below? It is the output of toString method of any object which wrap the MarkResponse? Or it is output which is print into your browser when you call any API? How it is possible that output consists [id=1, name=aaa] and not this {id=1, name=aaa} ?

Comment: The responses below are not JSON, that's for sure.

Comment: @Juraj - yes. It is to_string() . Here is the code : return new ResponseEntity<String>(response.toString(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works after changing the return type.

My earlier response was,

```
public ResponseEntity<String> fnCall() {
     //code here
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(MarkResponse.toString(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

I changed this to make it work.

```
  public MarkResponse fnCall() {
         //code here
         return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `private` fields. When I make fields `public`, jackson works and I don't need to objectMapper.disable(*anything*); when fields are private, or protected, or package-private, they are read, but not written to.

That is, assuming that you try to use `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` (yes, not the latest version) rather than something else that defines a class named ObjectMapper.